# AttributeError in Python program

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
import subprocess
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8', errors="backslashreplace").split("\n")
profiles = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data if"All User Profile" in i]
for i in profiles:
    try:
        results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key=clear']).decode('utf-8', errors="blackslashreplace").split("\n")
        results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if"Key Content" in b]
        try:
            print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i.results[0]))
        except IndexError:
            print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i, ""))
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i, "ENCODING ERROR"))
    input("")
```

That is my code, which for some reason throws that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manis\PycharmProjects\WiFi_Hacker\Hack.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i.results[0]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'results'
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: `for i in profiles` will iterate over the strings in the profiles list and put each string into `i`, so i will be of type `str` and that object has not attribute called results. So `i.results[0]` will error. did you mean to just call `results[0]`

Answer (score 0):

probably your problem is a typo:

`print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i.results[0]))`

instead of

`print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i,(COMMA, NOT DOT!)results[0]))`

`AttributeError` is thrown because `i` is a string, which obvoiusly doesnt have attribute(field or method) called `results`, which you're trying to get in this code.